# Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Suppose that $ghg^{-1}h^{-1} \in H$ for all $g \in G$ and $h\in H$. Show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Suppose that $ghg^{-1}h^{-1} \in H$ for all $g \in G$ and $h\in H$. Show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

I know I need to prove gH=Hg for all $g \in G$. However, I really don't know how to prove this.

Comment: Hint:  Pick $h_1\in H$ and $g\in G$.  By assumption there is some $h_2\in H$ with $gh_1g^{-1}h_1^{-1}=h_2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\forall g \in G$ and $h \in H$, $ghg^{-1}h^{-1} \in H$ means $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}=h_2$ for some $h_2 \in H$, then $ghg^{-1}=h_2h \in H$ which is the definition of $H$ being normal in G.